# Will Sim900A work in Angola(Africa)

Tags: sim900

We are using SIM900A IC in our project. I found out that SIM900A is region based. What I want to know, will my device will work in Angola Africa?.

If not then what will be a compatible IC(Pin o pin) which I can use.

Comment: Please provide a link to the data sheet and tell us what this device is supposed to do.

Comment: Google says: http://www.simcom.eu/index.php?m=termekek&prime=1&sub=40&id=0000000155

Answer (score 1):

The web page shows that the SIM900A is "dual-band GSM/GPRS 900/1800MHz".  That means it will only operate if you have GSM cell service at 900 or 1800 MHz. This is not "regional", it is based on what technology (GSM or CDMA) and what frequency bands (the most popular are 850, 900, 1800, and 1900 MHz) are used by the carrier of your choice in your area.

There are cell modules that will operate both GSM and CDMA, and are "quad-band" (operate at all four of the most popular frequency bands) that are typically used to have the best chance of operating in most places on the planet. Perhaps you should investigate using a "universal" quad-band cell module.

Answer (score 0):

This website lists that Angola does use 900 MHz and 1800 MHz, the band SIM900A uses, so it should work there.

http://www.worldtimezone.com/gsm.html